# Lost and "unacked" messages with Spring Integration AMQP and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am trying to create 2 simple applications; one is posting messages to RabbitMQ channel and the other one is receiving it from the channel and print them out the console. Sender app starts and post 10 messages immediately.

What I see on the client side console is only about half of the messages printed. 
I also see one of the messages always sits in the "Unacked" state when I checked the RabbitMQ web client.

When I read the documents, as far as I understand "amqp inbound/outbound gateway" is an easy way to implement this. 
Can you please help me to understand why I am loosing some messages and one sits in the "Unacked" state? 
Also, how should I change it to get all the messages on the other side?

Thank you in advance.

***Here are the xml configuration and files on sender side:***

**integrationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
  xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
  xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Configuration for Component Scan -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.amqp.sample" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:rabbitmq.properties"/>

<int:gateway id="taskGateway" service-interface="com.amqp.sample.TaskGateway" default-request-channel="processChannel" />
<int-amqp:channel id="processChannel"
   connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
   message-driven="true"
   queue-name="ha.rabbit.channel" />

<!-- RabbitMQ Connection Factory -->
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
    addresses="${rabbitmq.addresses}" 
    username="${rabbitmq.username}"
    password="${rabbitmq.password}" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" 
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    reply-timeout="-1" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />


<int-amqp:outbound-gateway  request-channel="processChannel" 
                            reply-channel="processChannel" 
                            reply-timeout="-1" />

</beans>
```

**TaskGateway.java**

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

import com.amqp.sample.model.Task;

public interface TaskGateway {

  void processTaskRequest(Message<Task> message);
}
```

**Task.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Task implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2138235868650860555L;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public Task(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

**Application.Java**

```
@PropertySources({
 @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:integrationContext.xml")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  private static TaskGateway taskGateway;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context=SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    taskGateway = context.getBean(TaskGateway.class);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      Message<Task> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(getTask(i)).build();
      taskGateway.processTaskRequest(message);
    }
  }

  /**
     * Creates a sample task returns.
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    private static Task getTask(final int id) {
        return new Task(id, "Task with ID:" + id);
    }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

}
```

***And, here are the files on receiver side:***

**integrationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
  xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
  xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <!-- Configuration for Component Scan -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.amqp.sample" />

  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:rabbitmq.properties"/>

  <!-- RabbitMQ Connection Factory -->
  <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        addresses="${rabbitmq.addresses}" 
        username="${rabbitmq.username}"
        password="${rabbitmq.password}" />

  <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
  <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

  <int:channel id="inputChannel"/>

  <int-amqp:inbound-gateway request-channel="inputChannel" reply-channel="inputChannel" 
    queue-names="ha.rabbit.channel" 
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
    amqp-template="amqpTemplate"/>

  <int:service-activator input-channel="inputChannel" ref="taskProcessService" method="process" />

</beans>
```

**ProcessService.java**

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

public interface ProcessService<T> {

    /**
     * Processes incoming message(s)
     *
     * @param message SI Message.
     */
    void process(Message<T> message);

}
```

**TaskProcessService**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.amqp.sample.model.Task;

@Component("taskProcessService")
public class TaskProcessService implements ProcessService<Task> {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskProcessService.class);

  @Override
  public void process(Message<Task> message) {

    logger.info("Received Message : " + message.getPayload());
  }

}
```

**Application.java**

```
@PropertySources({
 @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:integrationContext.xml")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, gateways are for request/reply scenarios; since your client expects no response and the service does not return one, you should be using channel adapters not gateways. Try that and get back if you are still having trouble.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class So40680673Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So40680673Application.class, args);
        FooGate gate = context.getBean(FooGate.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(gate.exchange("foo" + i));
        }
        context.close();
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "out.input")
    public interface FooGate {

        String exchange(String out);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow out(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        return f -> f.handle(Amqp.outboundGateway(amqpTemplate).routingKey(queue().getName()));
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow in(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(connectionFactory, queue().getName()))
                .<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new AnonymousQueue();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Gary. Actually, I am planning to log the message received on the sender side later on. This was one the reasons why I picked the gateways. Can you please help me to fix the code with the gateways?

Comment: With a reply timeout of -1 on the client side (`RabbitTemplate`); your calling thread will wait forever for a reply that's never coming. Once you fix that, I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages in both the client and server. I am not prepared to help debug a bogus configuration; sorry.

Comment: I understand. I will change the reply timeout and start the debugging from there. Meanwhile, do you have any simple integration-amqp with rabbitmq sample code/configuration using gateways which I can use as a sample? thanks again for your help.

Comment: I added an example; it uses the Java DSL instead of XML, but the functionality is the same.